# bootstrap: col width isn't working if other div is between "row" and "col-..."

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

I have the following html (in Angular):

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <app-tile *ngFor="let tile of tiles" [tile]="tile"></app-tile>
  </div>
</div>
```

The app-tile looks like this:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2">
...
</div>
```

The problem seems to be, that the container app-tile is between the classes "row" and "col-xs-12 col-sm-4 ...".
So the div inside the app-tile container hasn't the correct width specified by col-....

Some mandatories:

The width of the tile has to be set directly in the tile component, because it can be possible, that some tiles won't be displayed due to the user isn't permitted to see them. If i put the widths directly in the ngFor-Loop, the hidden tiles will have a blank container.

First Try: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wfjj5n?embed=1&file=src/app/alert-basic.html
Here the tiles have the correct width, but I have a blank container between first and third tile (because the second tile is hidden)

Second try: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wfjj5n-weuark?embed=1&file=src/app/tile/tile.component.ts
Moved the col-widths into the tile itself. Now the blank white container disappears, but the width of the tiles aren't correct anymore.

Comment: `width` is getting applied are you checking in responsive or mobile version ? if check desktop version you will see changes are there. @user2622344

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
 <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <app-tile *ngFor="let tile of tiles" [tile]="tile" [ngClass]="!isTileHidden(tile) ? 'col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2' : 'd-none'"></app-tile>
      </div>
    </div>
```

in your .ts

```
isTileHidden(tile) {
  if(// condition here) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```